# Select all sales from a certain date thats specified

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a coupon and would like to get all the rows that used a promo code after the creation date.

Each sale is timestamped and the coupon created is time stamped. Id like to select all the sales that are made after the coupon day.

Heres what I have.

```
$coupon = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM group_coupon WHERE code='test' AND active='1'");


if (count($coupon) > 0) {


  $amount = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM group_coupon WHERE code='test'")->row()->amount;

  $quantity = $coupon->row()->quantity;
    echo "Quantity: " . $quantity;

echo "Time: " . $coupon->row()->timestamp;

// I know the query is wrong 
$time_st = $coupon->row()->timestamp;
   $all = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sale WHERE coupon='test' AND $time_st > timestamp")->row()->coupon;

// then id like to do a count($all) 

}
```

Comment: What happens with this code? You are using sql-server or mysql?

Comment: mysql ---------

Comment: Okay, and what happens with this code? error, incorrect result, other?

Comment: $time_st is the timestamp that is created when coupon is created -- I need all the sales created after $time_st thats what I can't figure out

Answer (score 0):

You've made a bit of a logic error.

Let's say that the coupon you're checking was made at 1 pm and that time is represented by the number 100 (which is `$time_st` in this case). Then, there's another coupon made one hour after at 2 pm, represented by 200 (`timestamp`). You then check if `$time_st > timestamp` and this evaluates to `100 > 200` and this is not true.

What you want to do is check if the timestamp of the coupon you're checking is **less than** the other timestamps, so you know that they were made in the future.

Your query should be:

```
$all = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sale WHERE coupon='test' AND $time_st < timestamp")->row()->coupon;
```